# What mount points exist on a typical Linux system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, mount

I have 2 questions.

1. During Linux installation we specify memory space for 2 mount points - root and swap. Are there any other mount points created without the users notice?
2. Is this statement correct: "mounting comes into the picture only when dealing with different partitions. i.e, you cannot mount, say, /proc unless it's a different partition"?

Comment: +1 for question title! If all newbies asked so innocently...

Comment: Haha, *exactly* my thoughts too! +1.

Comment: @John: Asking two questions in one is not recommended. Since there are now answers that cover both questions, I guess we'll let it slide, but please ask separate questions separately next time. Your difficulty finding a good title (no, your title wasn't a good summary of your question) was due to trying to combine multiple questions into one.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are misconceptions behind your questions.

1. Swap is not mounted.
2. Mounting isn't limited to partitions.

### Partitions

A [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) is a slice¹ of disk space that's devoted to a particular purpose. Here are some common purposes for partitions.

- A [filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system), i.e. files organized as a directory tree and stored in a format such as ext2, ext3, FFS, FAT, NTFS, …
- Swap space, i.e. disk space used for [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) (and storing [hibernation images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_%28computing%29)).
- Direct application access. Some databases store their data directly on a partition rather than on a filesystem to gain a little performance. (A filesystem is a kind of database anyway.)
- A container for other partitions. For example, a [PC extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition), or a disk [slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_%28disk%29) containing BSD partitions, or an [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) physical volume (containing eventually logical volumes which can themselves be considered partitions), …

### Filesystems

[Filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/file_system) present information in a hierarchical structure. Here are some common kinds of filesystems:

- Disk-backed filesystems, such as ext2, ext3, FFS, FAT, NTFS, …

  - The backing need not be directly on a disk partition, as seen above. For example, this could be an [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) logical volume, or a [loop mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device).
- Memory-backed filesystems, such as Solaris and Linux's [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs).
- Filesystems that present information from the kernel, such as [`proc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) and [`sysfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) on Linux.
- Network filesystems, such as [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29), [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29), …
- Application-backed filesystems, of which [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) has a [large collection](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems). Application-backed filesystems can do just about anything: make an FTP server appear as a filesystem, give an alternate view of a filesystem where file names are case-insensitive or converted to a different encoding, show archive contents as if they were directories, …

### Mounting

Unix presents files in a single hierarchy, usually called “the filesystem” (but in this answer I'll not use the word “filesystem” in this sense to keep confusion down). Individual filesystems must be grafted onto that hierarchy in order to access them.³

You make a filesystem accessible by mounting it. Mounting associates the root directory of the filesystem you're mounting with a existing directory in the file hierarchy. A directory that has such an association is known as a mount point.

- For example, the root filesystem is mounted at boot time (before the kernel starts any process²) to the `/` directory.
- The proc filesystem over which some unix variants such as Solaris and Linux expose information about processes is mounted on `/proc`, so that `/proc/42/environ` designates the file `/42/environ` on the proc filesystem, which (on Linux, at least) contains a read-only view of the environment of process number 42.
- If you have a separate filesystem e.g. for `/home`, then `/home/john/myfile.txt` designates the file whose path is `/john/myfile.txt` from the root of the home filesystem.

Under Linux, it's possible for the same filesystem to be accessible through more than one path, thanks to [bind mounts](http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts).

A typical Linux filesystems has many mounted filesystems. (This is an example; different distributions, versions and setups will lead to different filesystems being mounted.)

- `/`: the root filesystem, mounted before the kernel loads the first process. The bootloader tells the kernel what to use as the root filesystem (it's usually a disk partition but could be something else such as an NFS export).
- `/proc`: the [proc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) filessytem, with process and kernel information.
- `/sys`: the [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) filesystem, with information about hardware devices.
- `/dev`: an in-memory filesystem where [device files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) are automatically created by [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) based on available hardware.
- `/dev/pts`: a special-purpose filesystem containing device files for running [terminal emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator).
- `/dev/shm`: an in-memory filesystem used for internal purposes by the system's standard library.
- Depending on what system components you have running, you may see other special-purpose filesystems such as `binfmt_misc` (used by the [foreign executable file format kernel subsystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)), `fusectl` (used by [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)), `nfsd` (used by the kernel NFS server), …
- Any filesystem explicitly mentioned in `/etc/fstab` (and not marked `noauto`) is mounted as part of the boot process.
- Any filesystem automatically mounted by [HAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_%28software%29) (or equivalent functionality) following the insertion of a removable device such as a USB key.
- Any filesystem explicitly mounted with the `mount` command.

¹  <sub>Informally speaking here.</sub> 
²  <sub>Initrd and such are beyond the scope of this answer.</sub> 
³  <sub>This is unlike Windows, which has a separate hierarchy for each filesystem, e.g. `c:` or `\\hostname\sharename`.</sub>

Comment: +10 Gilles where DO you get the time? My only comment is that I have to give people some slack on the swap issue because it's bloody confusing to have my swap partition listed in `/etc/fstab` when it's not to be mounted.

Comment: definitely a silly question... but can't stop myself. You said "Mounting associates a directory with the root of the filesystem." So where is "/" directory located?

Comment: @John: Not a silly question at all, the words “filesystem” and “root” have two different meanings here: there are individual filesystems (each with their root), and there's the whole directory hierarchy (with its root, the `/` directory). I've reworded this part of my answer, hopefully it should be clearer now.

Comment: That answer is so incredibly helpful - it's encyclopaedic. I, too, wish I could do a +10 here. Awesome answer.

Answer (score 14):

1. Every linux distro has its own default partition arrangement; some of them use dozens of partitions, some just a single one. 3 and 4 are quite common arrangements (/boot, /, swap and /home). Some older layouts often had /var on a separate partition and extreme systems hnd everything in /var/* and /opt/* on separate partitions! The best generalization I can make in answer to your question is that **nothing in the unix world is done without the users notice or ability to change it**!
2. You can mount things that are not partitions. For example /proc is not usually a partition, it is a pseudo filesystem provided by the kernel that allows you to read and write data about running processes as if they were files. You can also mount files (like ISO's) as if they were drives using a loopback device, bind mount folders to other places, and do various other ninja tricks.

Comment: All of the partitions that are automatically mounted on boot are in `/etc/fstab`.  If you add a partition there, it'll be there on the next boot.