# Partitioning with MS-DOS type

Tags: partition, fdisk

I need to partition an external HD, with FAT32.

Once upon a time, fdisk listed its possible partition types in a different, clearer way. 
The nearest entries now seem to be

```
10 Microsoft reserved             E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
11 Microsoft basic data           EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
12 Microsoft LDM metadata         5808C8AA-7E8F-42E0-85D2-E1E90434CFB3
13 Microsoft LDM data             AF9B60A0-1431-4F62-BC68-3311714A69AD
```

but I'm not clear about the difference.

Comment: Read it up here: https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html

Comment: thank you, you point exactly to the list I knew and used for years: the old fdisk partitions list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Partition System ID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60722/what-is-partition-system-id)

Comment: @Ulrich no, this question is about GPT partition types, not MBR partition types.

Comment: GPT "Microsoft ..." partition types are described in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-partition_information_gpt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re partitioning a disk with a [GUID partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), `fdisk` shows you [partition type GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) which are appropriate in that context, rather than the MBR partition types you’re used to.

In this particular case, you should choose type 11, “Microsoft basic data”.