# Partitions and the mounting points

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, block-device

An extract from a book-

> Linux organizes attached storage as **block devices**, you can move to
> the `/sys/block/` directory and list its contents. Among the contents
> will be a directory called `sda`/. (Remember that `sda` stands for
> **Storage Drive A**.) That’s the first drive used by your system on boot:
>
> Change to the `sda/` directory and run `ls`. Among its contents,
> you’ll probably see files with names like `sda1`, `sda2`, and `sda5`.
> Each of these represents one of the partitions created by Linux to
> better organize the data on your drive.

On my Ubuntu machine, the below partitions are shown for `sda`-

[image]

Running `df -h | grep sda` gives

[image]

As seen, `/dev/sda5` is mounted on '/' and `/dev/sda1` on `/boot/efi`.

Why is there no mounting point for partition `sda2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sda2` is an extended partition, which is a partition used with the MBR partitioning scheme to store other partitions. It contains `sda5`. It serves no purpose other than to store other partitions and is therefore not a candidate for mounting.

See [What mount points exist on a typical Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12040/86440) for details.